# How to view system cache memory on Windows 7

Tags: windows, caching, memory

As the title mentions, how is it possible to view cache memory on Windows 7?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which cache and for what purpose?

Comment: If you are interested in CPU cache sizes, then the function you want is [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the command line

wmic cpu get L2CacheSize, L2CacheSpeed, L3CacheSize, L3CacheSpeed

Returns cache sizes of the cpu

Answer (score 0):

Simply it can be done by built-in Windows command line tool wmic from Windows 10 command prompt. Search for ‘cmd’ in Windows 10 search and select the command prompt and type below command.

```
wmic cpu get L2CacheSize, L3CacheSize
```

It will return the details of your cache memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure that adds anything to the existing answer, though?